# Select data from multiple table where there may not necessarily be a match between some tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Trying to return the rest of the matches from other tables even if one of two table doesn't have a match. Best I can explain this, sorry.

Given the following tables

```
customers table
customerid    firstname    lastname   EmailAddress   etc...
   1           Tom         Smith     tsmith@abc.com  
   2           Mike        Adams     mikea@abc.com   
  etc...             

orders table
orderid      customerid        orderdate           etc..
 1            1            11/8/2007 8:53:00 AM 
 2            1            11/8/2007 8:53:00 AM
 3            2            11/8/2007 8:53:00 AM
 4            3            11/8/2007 8:53:00 AM
 5            4            11/8/2007 8:53:00 AM
 6            3            11/8/2007 8:53:00 AM
 7            5            11/8/2007 8:53:00 AM
 8            3            11/8/2007 8:53:00 AM

orderdetails table
orderid     productcode     productname    productprice    quantity    etc...
   1          widget1         widget 1        5.00             5
   2          widget2         widget 2        6.00             3
   3          widget3         widget 3        7.00             2
  etc...          

product table
vendor_partno    productcode     productprice      saleprice 
   wig1           widget1           10.00            7.50
   wig3           widget3            8.00  
   etc...
```

As you can see in the product table that widget2 product is no longer in the inventory. I am trying to select all product previously purchased by a specific customer based on there e-mail address and customer id. I need to display all products they have purchased even if it is not longer available in the product table.

The following query only shows those that are still in the products table.

What I want is to return all info shown in the select and if corresponding product info in the product table doesn't exist then just return the data that does exist.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), orders.orderdate, 101) AS OrderDate,
   orderdetails.orderid,
   orders.customerid,
   customers.emailaddress,
   orderdetails.productcode AS orig_product_code,
   orderdetails.productname,
   orderdetails.productprice,
   orderdetails.quantity,
   products_joined.vendor_partno,
   products_joined.productcode,
   products_joined.productprice AS current_reg_price,
   products_joined.saleprice AS current_sale_price
FROM orders,
   customers,
   orderdetails,
   products_joined
WITH (NOLOCK)      
WHERE 
   orders.orderid = orderdetails.orderid
   AND customers.customerid = orders.customerid
   AND orderdetails.productcode = products_joined.productcode
   AND customers.emailaddress = 'tsmith@abc.com'
   AND customers.customerid = '1' 
ORDER  BY orders.orderid DESC
```

Right now what is returned is

```
orderdate   orderid   customerid    emailaddress   orig_product_code   product name    product price   quantity   vendor_partno  productcode  current_reg_price   current_sale_price
11/8/2007      1          1        tsmith@abc.com     widget1            widget 1       5.00              5        wig1           widget1            10.00          7.50
```

What I would like returned is

```
orderdate   orderid   customerid    emailaddress   orig_product_code   product name    product price   quantity   vendor_partno  productcode  current_reg_price   current_sale_price
11/08/2007      1          1        tsmith@abc.com        widget1         widget 1       5.00              5        wig1        widget1            10.00            7.50    
11/08/2007      2          1        tsmith@abc.com     widget2            widget 2       6.00              3
```

Obviously the reason for this is

```
orderdetails.productcode = products_joined.productcode
```

but i am not sure how to get fix this.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need an outer join with the products_joined table like below.

Also it would be a good idea to use modern JOIN syntax; ie. put all join conditions into the JOIN clause rather than the WHERE clause, like so:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), orders.orderdate, 101) AS OrderDate,
       orderdetails.orderid,
       orders.customerid,
       customers.emailaddress,
       orderdetails.productcode AS orig_product_code,
       orderdetails.productname,
       orderdetails.productprice,
       orderdetails.quantity,
       products_joined.vendor_partno,
       products_joined.productcode,
       products_joined.productprice AS current_reg_price,
       products_joined.saleprice AS current_sale_price
  FROM orders
  join customers
    on customers.customerid = orders.customerid
  join orderdetails
    on orders.orderid = orderdetails.orderid
  left join products_joined
    on orderdetails.productcode = products_joined.productcode
 WHERE customers.emailaddress = 'tsmith@abc.com'
   AND customers.customerid = '1'
 ORDER BY orders.orderid DESC
```

Comment: Yes, left join did the trick. Now why couldn't I think of that, lol. and yes using joins would be better.